# Why Rig Veda II.7.5 says that Agni was the descendant of Bharata?

Tags: rig-veda, agni, bharata

Rig Veda II.7.5 says as follows:

> तवं नो असि भारताग्ने वशाभिरुक्षभिः |  अष्टापदीभिराहुतः ||

[Translation of H.H. Wilson](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/159) is as follows:

> AGNI. **descendant of Bharata**, thou art entirely ours, when sacrificed
> to with pregnant kine, with barren cows or bulls

My question is why AGNI was called as descendant of Bharata?  Did AGNI take birth in the family of Bharata?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YztNe.png) is the Sayanacharya's commentary may be useful if one wants to refer.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā: Sayana says bhArata means sprung from the priests - producing by their rubbing together their sticks together.  Dictionary says bharata means a priest - sage

Comment: Must be an interpolation.

Comment: If you say so, then it must be an interpretation @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 1):

According to [H.H. Wilson (P.311)](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/339), Sayana says bhArata means sprung from the priests - producing AGNI by their rubbing together their sticks together.

---

The Rig Veda [III.29.2 & III.29.6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03029.htm) clarified this issue.

> In the ***two fire-sticks Jātavedas lieth***, even as the well-set germ in
> pregnant women, Agni who day by day must be exalted by men who watch
> and worship with oblations.
>
> **When with their arms** they rub him straight ***he shineth forth*** like a
> strong courser, red in colour, in the wood. Bright, checkless, as it
> were upon the Aśvins' path, he passeth by the stones and burneth up
> the grass.

---

Comment: Must be an interpolation.

Comment: If you say so, then it must be an interpretation @Ikshvaku